# I'm not able to focus on any entry and not able to click on any checkbox/radio button inside bindable stack layout in iOS .net maui

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

I'm not able to focus on any entry and not able to click on any checkbox/radio button inside bindable stack layout from second row in .net maui for iOS. android is working fine.

here is the screenshot of what i'm trying to do.

[image]

here is the code.

```
<VerticalStackLayout  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource 00dp}"  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding inspectionData.inspectionSection}">
<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>    
        <VerticalStackLayout >                   
            <Border  Margin="10,20,10,10" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource 02dp}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource roundedBorderStyleGray}" >
                                        <VerticalStackLayout>
                <HorizontalStackLayout >
                    <Label FontFamily="OpenSansSemiBold" Margin="15,20,10,10" Text="{Binding title}"  TextColor="{StaticResource TrackemOrange}"/>                         
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                   
                 <VerticalStackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding inspectionQuestion}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <VerticalStackLayout>
                                <Border Margin="10,0,10,10" Padding="5,5,5,5" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource 00dp}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource roundedBorderStyleBlack}" >
                                
                                    <VerticalStackLayout   >
                                        <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="15,15,0,10" >
                                            <Label FontFamily="OpenSansSemiBold" Margin="0,3,0,0" FontSize="14"   Text="Q: "  TextColor="White"/>
                                            <Label Padding="15,3,0,10" FontFamily="OpenSansRegular"  Text="{Binding questionText}" TextColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                                                        
                                        <BoxView   Background="#2D2D30" HeightRequest="1" />

                                        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="0,15,0,10" IsVisible="{Binding isShowText}">
                                            <Frame HasShadow="False"  BorderColor="#2D2D30" Background="transparent" Padding="0" Margin="15,0,15,0">

                                                <commonviews:BorderlessTextEntry  Text="{Binding answerText}"  HeightRequest="40" PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource TrackemDisabled}"  Placeholder="Answer" TextColor="{StaticResource TrackemWhite}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                            </Frame>
                                        </VerticalStackLayout>

                                        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="0,15,0,10" IsVisible="{Binding allowComment}">

                                            <Frame HasShadow="False"  BorderColor="#2D2D30" Background="transparent" Padding="0" Margin="15,0,15,0" >

                                                <commonviews:BorderlessTextEntry  Text="{Binding comment}"  HeightRequest="40"  Placeholder="Comment" PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource TrackemDisabled}" TextColor="{StaticResource TrackemWhite}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                                            </Frame>

                                        </VerticalStackLayout>            
                                    </VerticalStackLayout>

                                 </Border>


                             </VerticalStackLayout>
                                                
                         </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>

                 </VerticalStackLayout>                    


                  </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Border>                       
        </VerticalStackLayout>
                           
    </DataTemplate>
</BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

not sure, what i did wrong here. can someone please help me here. it's working as expected in android.

Comment: Seems likely to be a Maui bug; I think it is worth reporting. If you want, make a new solution, with a new Maui project template. Copy just enough code from your project, with some fake "hardcoded" data, so anyone can build and run, to see the symptom. Put solution in a public github repo. Create a new Maui issue at `github maui issues`. Describe like you did here, and add link to repo. Then add a link here at StackOverflow, to that issue.

Answer (score 1):

**from second row** is the essential point here.

`<VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">` on `ItemTemplate.`

You tell **each item** to try to take the entire height. That can't be a good idea.

- Remove `VerticalOptions`.

Comment: Side note, but worth mentioning in this context: The `*AndExpand` options are deprecated in MAUI and shouldn't be used anymore. Before, in Xamarin.Forms, it was recommended to use any of the `*AndExpand` options on only one of the child elements of a StackLayout for performance reasons.

Comment: I've updated my code @ewerspej please have a look once

Comment: Did this change the symptom at all? Might be a bug in Maui; need to do some tests to isolate the cause. If you REMOVE all the `Border`s and `Frame`s, does it work?

Comment: Nope, not working. Let me try to remove border and frames.

Comment: Hiii @ToolmakerSteve, I've tried to remove border and frame. i'm getting same. no changes. I'm not able to access third row now

Comment: You'll have to make a public github repo, so someone can look at it. See my comment on question.

Comment: OK, let me create